# Rewrite algorithm as a template function to compare 2 values

Tags: c++

I am trying to rewrite the selection sort algorithm below as a template function that compares two elements.

here is my sorting algorithm

```
    #include <iostream>

#include "util.h"

/** 
    Gets the position of the smallest element in a vector range.
    @param a the vector
    @param from the beginning of the range
    @param to the end of the range
    @return the position of the smallest element in 
    the range a[from]...a[to]
*/
int min_position(vector<int>& a, int from, int to)
{  
   int min_pos = from;
   int i;
   for (i = from + 1; i <= to; i++)
      if (a[i] < a[min_pos]) min_pos = i;
   return min_pos;
}

/** 
   Sorts a vector using the selection sort algorithm
   @param a the vector to sort
*/

void selection_sort(vector<int>& a)
{  
   int next; // The next position to be set to the minimum

   for (next = 0; next < a.size() - 1; next++)
   {  
      // Find the position of the minimum
      int min_pos = min_position(a, next, a.size() - 1);
      if (min_pos != next)
         swap(a[min_pos], a[next]);
   }
}

int main()
{  
   rand_seed();
   vector<int> v(20);
   for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      v[i] = rand_int(1, 100);
   print(v);
   selection_sort(v);
   print(v);
   return 0;
}
```

I wrote a template to compare the values, but I am having trouble implementing it on my program above.

```
template <typename T> 
void sort(T A[],int N) 
{  

 for(int n = 1;n < N;n++) {
     T mover = A[n];
     int k = n;
     while(k > 0) {
       if(A[k-1] > mover) {
         A[k] = A[k-1];
        k--;
       } else
         break;
     }
     A[k] = mover;   
} 

}
```

I am new to c++ and templates/sorting is giving me fits, so I am looking for some assistance or guidance.

thanks

Comment: Can you just use `std::sort` instead of writing it yourself? Is this an exercise? Also, `min_position` already exists as `std::min_element`.

Comment: It would help us if you could tell us *what* trouble you have.

Comment: @Mark Yes this is an exercise for class. My original programs does a sort, but I am not sure how to rewrite the program as a function. I can write the function independently, which I did, but I am having trouble rewriting the program.